# User Interaction on UIAlert

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, apple-push-notifications, uialertview

Facebook Messenger application dismisses a UIViewController automatically after the user interacts with the Push Notification alert message. 
I'm wondering how they detect the user has clicked one of the actions on the alert view.

I have tried to implement a specific solution based on the push notification delegate methods:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)
```

Unfortunately this is not really reliable, especially for devices that are already registered to push notifications.

This is a youtube video with the workflow implemented by Facebook

https://www.youtube.com/embed/sCg3vYx9hlw

UPDATE:

The problem is that  this method get called when the user has previously deleted the app and was already registered for push notifications. In this case isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications is false, so I ask to registerForRemoteNotifications. When the alert is shown 
- application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
is invoked even if the user has not clicked any option in the alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS8 and later registering for notifications going like this:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

And in AppDelegate `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` method called when user interacted with the Push Notification alert message, here you register for notifications. In this delegate method you can check whether the app is allowed to receive push notification and with what notification types :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    // here you can check notification settings
    // and do some ui changes

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Comment: I have update the answer with more details. Sometimes this method get called even if the user has not clicked any options in the alert dialog.

Comment: You are talking about `registerForRemoteNotifications` and `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` and `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`. I'm talking about `registerUserNotificationSettings`. Please make sure that you didn’t make a mistake.